# Array does not reset after update value in firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to angular and when I'm update a value in firebase everything goes well. But after the update it needs to clear the array. I tried a lot of things but the array keeps it values. What did i wrong?

I created a function to empty the array after the update i tried two method:

method one:

```
 this.values = [];
```

method two:

```
this.values.length = 0;
```

This is the current code:

```
values = [10,10];

getSum(total,num){
    return total + num;
  }

  updateFirebase(){
    var newTotal;
    newTotal = this.values.reduce(this.getSum);
    this.db.object('/mangement/sittardData/4').update({
      total: newTotal,
    });

    this.empytArray();

  }

  empytArray(){
    return this.values = [];
  }
```

The function will be called when adding a value, next it will reduce the values in the array, in this example it should be 20. this 20 should be saved to the firebase object total. after this the array needs to be cleared. but i keeps it values, what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you ensured that `empytArray` is in fact being called (e.g. through breakpoints or `console.log`)? Are you getting your expected result in your Firebase DB? Are you getting any errors on your update call that are preventing `this.emptyArray()` from being reached?

Comment: i have console logged it and emptyArrat gets called, the first time i'm getting the expected value in FB but not when i run this code the second time, and no i don't get any errors in my console.log

Comment: presumably because the update is an async function so it doesn’t get called in time before your it runs again